# Extracting .text returns an empty string while scraping Google Scholar with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

I want to scrape the information on this page (https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ&hl=en#). On the page a bar graph with the number of citations every year. I would like to scrape both years and citations in a list or a table, but so far I have not been able to scrape the number of citations, but the years. Do you have any advice to crawl and parse the data?
Thanks in advance,
Iván

```
from selenium import webdriver
mozilla_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\Python38\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ&hl=en")
driver.maximize_window()
Table=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="gsc_rsb_cit"]/div/div[3]/div""") .click()
Years=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='gsc_g_t']")
#for Year in Years:
#   print(Year.text)
Citations=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='gsc_g_a']")
#for Citation in Citations:
#    print(Citation)
page_items=len(Years)
for i in range(page_items):
    print(Years(i).text , " : " , Citations(i).text)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is not displayed on the page, so .text does not extract it (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463974/python-selenium-xpath-geting-text-is-empty)).

You can use .get_attribute("textContent") which works:

```py
import os
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = os.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER_PATH")

url = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=8Cuk5vYAAAAJ&hl=en"

driver = Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

years = [element.get_attribute("textContent") for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gsc_g_t"]')]
citations = [element.get_attribute("textContent") for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="gsc_g_al"]')]

for year, citation in zip(years, citations):
    print(year, citation)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an additional solution to [Raphael Meudec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016296/15164646) answer but using `beautifulsoup` to solve this question. It contains pretty much the same code and logic as Raphael used.

You need to use it with a proxy if the headers didn't help, otherwise, Google Scholar will block a request because the automation script sends requests.

Adding proxy to request, assuming you'll be using `requests` library, e.g:

```py
proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
}

# Request will be like so:
requests.get('google scholar link', proxies=proxies)
```

Code ([full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-Python-SerpApi#main.py) in the online IDE under bs4 folder -> bs4_author_citedby_results):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
}


html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=m8dFEawAAAAJ', headers=headers, proxies=proxies).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# This is basically the same as Raphael Meudec suggested but using beautifulsoup
years = [graph_year.text for graph_year in soup.select('.gsc_g_t')]
citations = [graph_citation.text for graph_citation in soup.select('.gsc_g_a')]

for year, citation in zip(years,citations):
  print(f'{year} {citation}\n')


# Part of the output:
'''
2007 24

2008 30

2009 46
'''
```

Or you can make a JSON output like so by adding `data.append()` inside `zip()` for loop:

```py
data = []

for year, citation in zip(years,citations):

  data.append({
    'year': year,
    'citation': citation,
  })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

# Part of the output:
'''
[
  {
    "year": "2007",
    "citation": "24"
  },
  {
    "year": "2008",
    "citation": "30"
  }
]
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Scholar Author Cited By API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-cited-by) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "8Cuk5vYAAAAJ",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for graph_results in results['cited_by']['graph']:
  year = graph_results['year']
  citations = graph_results['citations']
  print(f'{year} {citations}\n')

# part of the output
# JSON output could be added in the same manner as with bs4 code.
'''
2007 24

2008 30

2009 46
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.